# Alter a table column into smallint column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a **postgres** table called **update_profile** with a column that is a table:
[image]

And I want to **alter** this column to a **smallint** containing the value of ***update_type_id***.

Initially I tried:

```sql
ALTER TABLE update_profile ALTER COLUMN update_type TYPE SMALLINT USING update_type.update_type_id;
```

But I had the following error: **missing FROM-clause entry for table "update_type"**

Then I tried:

```sql
ALTER TABLE update_profile AS u ALTER COLUMN u.update_type TYPE SMALLINT USING u.update_type.update_type_id;
```

Which is not allowed.

Note: **update_type_id** is also a **smallint**

Is there a way to do this operation?

Comment: What is the _real_ problem you are trying to solve here? Once you have done this, you have two columns with exactly the same content and definition. What's the purpose of that?

Comment: So later I can make update_type_id a foreign key and also since we don't have any other column as a table I want to normalize it

Comment: The `update_type` column seems completely useless in that case. Why not simply drop it entirely?

Comment: Because this table needs the value `update_type`. But you gave me an idea, I could create a new column called `update_type_id`, pass the content of `update_type.update_type_id` there and then delete `update_type`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't repeat the table name when you reference the other column. You can't assign any alias for the table (or column) either.

```
ALTER TABLE update_profile 
   ALTER COLUMN update_type TYPE SMALLINT
   USING update_type_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```sql
ALTER TABLE update_profile ADD COLUMN update_type_id SMALLINT;

UPDATE update_profile up SET update_type_id =
(
    SELECT ut.update_type_id
    FROM n3rgy_update_type ut
    WHERE ut = up.update_type
)
WHERE up.update_type IS NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE update_profile DROP COLUMN update_type;
```

Because I didn't find a way to alter the column `update_type`, I created a new column called `update_type_id`, passed the values of `update_profile.update_type.update_type_id`, and then dropped `update_type`.

So now I have the values of `update_profile.update_type.update_type_id` in `update_profile.update_type_id`